# sql incorporating c++

Tags: c++, sql

i'm writing sql and c++ code that adds a technician into the database. there's 3 sql insert statements that has to be performed. i have that include in my code, but my code doesn't conform or do what is asked. here is what is asked.

the program should prompt the user for an ssn.

if that ssn/employee is already in the Employee table, the program should inform the user that the employee is already in the DB and ask the user if he wants to update the union-membership-number of that employee; if the user’s answer is yes, the program should ask the user for the new union-member-number and update it in the DB.

if the ssn/employee is not already in the DB, the program should ask the user for the union-membership-number of that employee and then store that record in the Employee table. Assuming the employee is a technician the program should ask the user for the information to be stored about that technician (name, address and phone number) and store it in the Technician table; then the program should ask the user for the airplane model-number that the technician is an expert on and add the corresponding record into the Experts table.

here is my code:

```
void add_technician() {
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    char sn[9];
    int s=0;
    char answer;
    int umn;
    char tname[30];
    char tadd[30];
    char tpho[10];
    char tmod[15];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

cout << "Enter social security number:";
cin >> sn;  

EXEC SQL SELECT SSN into :s from Employee where SSN= :sn;

          if (s == sn)
   { 
cout << "Employee already exists in the database."; 
   cout <<"Would you like to update the union-membership-number?";
   cin >> answer;
   if (answer == 'y'|| 'Y')
   {cout <<"Enter new union member number:";
   cin >> umn;
EXEC SQL 
    INSERT INTO Employee (ssn, union_member_no)
    VALUES (:sn, :umn);
 } 
   }
         else {
 cout << "Enter in union membership number of the new employee: ";
            cin >> umn;
            EXEC SQL INSERT INTO Employees (ssn, union_member_no) 
                   VALUES (:sn, :umn);
            EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK;
             cout << "Enter the address of the technician.";
             cin >> tadd;
 cout << "Enter the name technician name.";
             cin >> tname;

            EXEC SQL INSERT INTO Technicians (address, name, phone)
       VALUES (:tadd, :tname, :tpho);
EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK;
            cout << "Enter airplane model number that you are an expert on." ;
            cin >> tmod;
EXEC SQL INSERT INTO Experts (model_no, ssn)
    VALUES (:tmod);
EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK; }                

}
```

when i run the program, it skips my first two IF statements. i can't seem to understand why.

Comment: @joeframbach did you modify my code or something?

Comment: I added the "c++" tag to the question.

Comment: I see that you changed the if(s == sn) but in order for this to work, you need to change the EXEC statement as well (that a look at my proposed answer). The count(*) is not right.

Comment: i also did change the exec sql in my code, but forgot to change it here. even after i changed it, i still get a error message saying C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Comment: sn is a char[] and s is an int this is why.

Comment: if i change sn to an int, the pre-compiler says that arrays can't be used in the exec sql in from/where clause

Comment: is there something else i could try?

Answer (score 0):

Your way of storing the value back into s is not right.

Take a look over for a good example [ESQL Programmer's guide](http://www.dbmaker.com/download/manual/esql.pdf)

I would say that you're having a MySQL approach to the problem. Instead, I would do something like this (rough approach):

```
int s = 0;
EXEC SQL SELECT rowSSN into :s from Employee where SSN= :sn;

if (s == sn) 
...
```

The value of s is actually the value of the row it self.
Consider looking at CURSOR to have an approach by counter the number of rows comming back from the query.

Comment: what i was checking for with that is to see if the value to user entered in for the ssn is in the database. howcome you would use if (s > 0)? and also int s = -1?

Comment: if your if statement, would it would if(s==:sn) or no?

Comment: I updated my answer in regards to your comment. 
1) int s = 0; simply to initialize the varible for the comparison with the if clause.
2) if the result is found on the database, then s will be equal to the ssn number that the user entered. You can then treat the information accordingly.

Comment: i edited my program and now i receive the following errors. 


sql.cpp: In function `void add_technician()':
sql.cpp:652: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Comment: Take a look over here : http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-proc.html . This example uses pretty much the same problem you use for your program (SSN). Look under **PROC SYNTAX**

Comment: with that, it's specifying a specific ssn, not one that the user enters in. i not able to see how that would really help me out.